# emacs remove macOS Tags when resave the file

Tags: osx

I found `emacs` cannot save the macOS tag when the file changed and save from buffer

[image: macOS tag]

I create a empty file with macOS tag

[image: create a empty file with macOS tag]

and use emacs to open it and write something

use C-x C-s to save and the tags in Finder disappeared

[image: after save]

How could I have a method to reserve these tags when I resave it?

Comment: I cannot imagine that the vanilla Emacs development team has invented a way to deal with MacOS file tags.  This is the first time that I've even heard of system file tags, probably because I still use OSX 10.6.8 at home and El Capitan when on the road.  Most likely, you will need to submit a feature request to the main development team.  In the alternative, there is a modified version of Emacs called Mac Port (Yamamoto Mitsuharu) that has system specific features / enhancements -- it may be worthwhile to submit a feature request to them also.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this  behavior with Emacs 25.3.1 on El Capitan (Mac OS 10.11.6). If I add a tag to a file and edit it in Emacs the tags persist

Comment: Tags are stored as extended file attributes, under `com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags`.  But `file-extended-attributes` doesn't know them.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how the tags are implemented but if they are associated to the inode and not to the name you can try to set the variable `backup-by-copying` to `t`.

When emacs creates a backup  normally renames the old file and create a new one with the new content ([see the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup-Copying.html)), when `backup-by-copying` is `t` it copies the old file to create a backup and writes the new content in the old one.

Comment: I use open(2) to change a file and the tag don't disappear. I don't know how does emacs implement saving file.

Comment: Can confirm that `backup-by-copying` works for this as "advertised". Thanks for the tip!